# What is the proper way to get new comments on my youtube channels in youtube-data-api

Tags: youtube-data-api

Currently I am fetching all comments on loop over videos. Is there any other way to get latest comments better. I means looping thousands of videos and getting just 10 new comments is time and resource consuming. Is there any good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not currently possible to get multiple Video's comments in one API call. See the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list).

You would have to iterate through each video and get the comments for each one which would be very costly on quota but necessary.